# Registration of work item handler failed in Ubuntu, but not in Red Hat

Tags: ubuntu, exception, jbpm, jboss6.x, workitem

I´ve been struggling with this issue for days and i can´t understand why this happens.

I´m using **jbpm 5.4** and also de jbpm-gwt-console-server services (like list all de process definitions and so on)

Everything works just fine in **Red Hat**, but when we changed to **Ubuntu**, using the exactly jboss (6.3.0) with the exactly jbpm wars and session.template, no workitem can be initialized.

If anyone has a clue what this could be, thanks.

This is the **exception** throwed:

`ERROR [org.jbpm.integration.console.session.MVELSingleSessionManager] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-20) Registration of work item handler UpdateAssetMetadatav1 failed due to [Error: could not create constructor: null]
[Near : {... new br.com.arizona.bpm.workItem.cm ....}]
                 ^
[Line: 1, Column: 5]: [Error: could not create constructor: null]
[Near : {... new br.com.arizona.bpm.workItem.cm ....}]
                 ^
[Line: 1, Column: 5]
        at org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.optimizeObjectCreation(ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.java:1229) [mvel2-2.1.3.Final.jar:]
        at org.mvel2.optimizers.dynamic.DynamicOptimizer.optimizeObjectCreation(DynamicOptimizer.java:98) [mvel2-2.1.3.Final.jar:]
        at org.mvel2.ast.NewObjectNode.getReducedValueAccelerated(NewObjectNode.java:214) [mvel2-2.1.3.Final.jar:]
        at org.mvel2.MVELRuntime.execute(MVELRuntime.java:85) [mvel2-2.1.3.Final.jar:]
        at org.mvel2.compiler.CompiledExpression.getDirectValue(CompiledExpression.java:123) [mvel2-2.1.3.Final.jar:]
        at org.mvel2.compiler.CompiledExpression.getValue(CompiledExpression.java:119) [mvel2-2.1.3.Final.jar:]
        at org.mvel2.compiler.CompiledExpression.getValue(CompiledExpression.java:113) [mvel2-2.1.3.Final.jar:]
        at org.mvel2.MVEL.executeExpression(MVEL.java:969) [mvel2-2.1.3.Final.jar:]`

Answer (score 1):

Well,

Just for reference, if someone's interested.

In a certain point i was certain that it was conflict between jars in the classpath and the log was hiding the real problem.
So I had to debug it to see the real exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Objects.firstNonNull.

After this I discovered that a transient dependence google-collections was been use for that class instead of guava.

Solution, simple as it is (but not so simple to find it, because of the misleading log) : remove google-collections from de classpath.

However I still doesn't understand why in redhat it was accessing the right class, but not in Ubuntu. Anyway, it is working now.

Cheers